# Why do we grant access to our funds instead of just sending them to the smart contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, erc-20, defi

In DeFi I have seen that users are prompted to give access to their funds. Why not just send those funds to the smart contract instead?

What is the advantage of this design?

Comment: I believe it's for security reasons. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67384106/ehtereum-smart-contract-approve-spender-from-another-contract?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "advantage". The reason most DeFi apps ask users to "allow" the transfer of their funds is that those funds are represented as [ERC-20](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/understand-the-erc-20-token-smart-contract) tokens. The Ethereum community is confronted with an instance of the classical [path dependence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_dependence) problem.

Here's a [guide](https://tokenallowance.io/) that dives deep into ERC-20 allowances. And here are some practical solutions:

- [ERC-20 Permit](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2612): adds a "permit" function to the ERC-20 standard.
- [ERC-777](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-777): a new token standard altogether. This doesn't have much traction as far as I know.

Comment: In the [guide](https://tokenallowance.io/) you have posted in your answer it says: 

`"Because the Ethereum blockchain allows transactions with smart contracts and those  smart contracts can be facilitated by 3rd parties – like a DEX or Protocol Relayer –
permissions have to be granted to the 3rd party by token owners before those smart contracts can execute."`

How is a dex a third party if the smart contract is the dex?

Comment: It is possible for a DeFi frontend app to integrate a protocol that they didn't build themselves. E.g. [1inch.io](https://1inch.io), which is an aggregator of DEXes. But yes, when the creator of DeFI frontend is the same as the creator of the DEX, there is no third-party.

Comment: If my answer helped you, could you hit the upvote button, or potentially mark the answer as accepted?

Comment: Now I see how third parties come in play. Thank you. So if there is no third party do you need the 'allowance method' ? Also, in your answer, you have said `The reason most DeFi apps ask users to "allow" the transfer of their funds is that those funds are represented as ERC-20 tokens.` What do you mean by this? If they weren't ERC 20 tokens there would be no need for the 'allow' functionality? You have also talked about [path dependence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_dependence) does this mean that the allow method is currently unnecessary?

Comment: If there is no third-party but the tokens are ERC-20, you still need allowances. The token smart contracts would be the same.

Comment: If they weren't ERC-20 tokens, then yes, *potentially* there would be no need for users to approve the tokens before transferring them. Read about `ERC20Permit` and `ERC-777`.

Comment: Re path dependence - what I meant is that ERC-20 is an old standard. It dates back to 2016. Lots of things improved in Ethereum in the meantime. If we were to design a token standard from scratch, we would make it quite different today.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, there are two ways to transfer (ERC20) tokens:

1. Direct transfer with `transfer`. You can call this function to transfer your tokens directly to another address.
2. Indirect transfer with `approve` and `transferFrom`. This way you do two different transaction: first you give approval for the receiver to withdraw your tokens. Then you call some functionality in the receiver, and that executes `transferFrom` which takes your tokens.

I think there are two advantages of using the indirect method:

1. Functionality. If you use a direct transfer, the receiver has no idea he has received tokens. You would anyway need a second transaction to tell the receiver that "hey, I sent you tokens, now do your part of the deal", and you'd suffer also in security. Also, with approvals, if you trust the receiver, you can just approve all of your tokens and do multiple trades with the same approval - so just one approval and multiple "second" transactions.
2. Security. It's harder to trick users into sending tokens to the wrong place if it requires two separate transactions. Also, this way you can in advance read the receiver's contract code and see what happens when you do the second transaction. With direct transfer you'd simply have to hope that the receiver does what it promised to do.

Comment: First: Why not just have a function that is payable that users call and it executes the necessary code? Second: Wouldn't my first point mean that you can still, in advance, read the receiver's contract code and see what happens when you do the second transaction?

Comment: Payable function has nothing to do with transfering tokens; it's only used for Ether transfers. Tokens are always transferred by calling the token contract's functionality

Comment: Now I understand. To the blockchain all you are doing is calling another smart contract's function.